# Unpredictable routing in nextjs when routing from a nested route

Tags: typescript, next.js

i created a folder called `dashboard` in pages folder which has the following files:

1. index.tsx
2. customers.tsx
3. invoice.tsx
4. items.tsx

when a user routes to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` the `index.tsx` page is rendered. However when i click a button and route to invoices or customers i get a `404 page` when i check the url it routed to `http://localhost:3000/customers` and `http://localhost:3000/invoices` instead of `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/customers` and `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/invoices`

But when I try and write the full route in the href for customers:

```js
//It will work after refreshing the page
<Link href='dashboard/customers'>
  <a>Customers</a>
</Link>
```

And when I try to route to any routes from customers to any nested page e.g:

```js
<Link href='dashboard/invoices'>
  <a>Customers</a>
</Link>
// I tend to get a 404 page
```

When I checked the url it did the following: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dashboard/invoices` instead of `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/invoices`

Code below for the buttons:

```js
<Link href='/customers'>
  <a>Customers</a>
</Link>

<Link href='/invoices'>
  <a>Invoices</a>
</Link>
```

Really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Link href='dashboard/invoices' />` is a relative route - `href='dashboard/invoices'` means to go to `/yourCurrentLocation/dashboard/invoices`.

For an absolute route, you must prepend with a `/`. This means it'll always be routed relative to the root directory. Thus, your code should be `<Link href='/dashboard/invoices' />`.

Comment: can't avoid thanking you even tho the placeholder tells me not to.